# app is redirected to browser when I do a redirection in Cordova

Tags: cordova

My apps consits in a redirection to a website.
In previous apps I did, when I did the redirection it opened the website in the app, not in the browser.
To do the last one I upgraded cordova, gradle and android-studio.

Which version do I need to open the website in the app ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in old versions, there were no whitelists included. In newer versions, now every urls outside your network are blacklisted. This means that if you use a link (an html "a" tag) then it will throw an error. If you use `window.location` in js or something similar, cordova will open it in the browser.
So in order to fix that, you will need to whitelist the domain you want to access.

In your config.xml, add this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

<allow-navigation href="https://example.com/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://example.com/*" />
<access origin="https://example.com/*" />
```

You can use the wildcard * to include everything in a folder/domain/subdomain, like shown above but you don't have to use it. You can add a url like: `https://mywebsite.com/myfolder/index.php`. If you do like this, you may need to whitelist multiple urls if your client need to load resources. For example:

if your client loads JQuery from a cdn, then you will need to whitelist that url too.

Of course make sure you replace example.com with your domain name or url

Also make sure you trust the source you whitelist because then people may be able to load scripts and pages from these sources into your app to deceive users using your app.

As for the Cordova version, I don't really think it matters but if I were you I would use the lastest, because it supports better newer android versions such as android 9 & 10.